# Lyx: How to align graphic with text line?

Tags: lyx, vertical-alignment

I try to insert small PNG clips into a line of text. So far, the graphic is aligned with the baseline of the text, but since the PNG needs to be a little larger than the text height for readability, it sticks out at the upper end. Example below:
[image: Sample image]

I'd rather like to have the vertical center of the graphic align with the vertical center of the text but see no way of fine-adjusting the vertical position of it. All that is available in LyX for the vertical position of single words seems to be super- and subscript, but subscripting it moves the graphic too far down.

Comment: Maybe you'll have to delve into the LaTeX code.

Comment: you can use `\raisebox{-5pt}{\includegraphics{imagename}}` but I have no idea how to do that from lyx.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: This did the trick, thank you. LyX allows to insert LaTeX code directly (called ERT for evil red text) and that does indeed place the graphic where it belongs. I only added a [height=5mm] to scale the graphic as desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
 \raisebox{-5pt}{\includegraphics[height=whatever]{imagename}}
```

apparently as a lyx ERT to allow direct insert of TeX markup.